# Preg replace (.*) function from PHP to javascript (str_replace)

Tags: javascript

I want to do a replace in javascript, but like the preg replace function from PHP.

There's a symbol to enter that allow get a string that is between "T='" and "'", as example.

Like this (**preg_replace** function, PHP):

```
$str = '<s L="200" H="200" T="0"/>';
echo preg_replace('L="(.*)"', 'style="width: \\1px;"', $str);
```

This above is the what I want to do.

I wanted to know if there's a method to do this in javascript.

Do know some way?

Comment: I think you are looking for [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: though I'm not entirely clear about what you are actually trying to match and replace.. I mean, that's not even valid `preg_replace` syntax..

Comment: `<script>
var myString = "<ground L='120'/>";

function string_between(leftStr, rightStr, strInto) {
 var strBtwnThis = strInto.substring(strInto.lastIndexOf(leftStr)+leftStr.length,strInto.lastIndexOf(rightStr));
 return strBtwnThis;
}

document.write(string_between("L='", "'", myString));
</script>`, I already get, but don't deleted the answer. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent in Javascript is:

```js
str = '<s L="200" H="200" T="0"/>';
alert(str.replace(/L="(.*)"/g, 'style="width: $1px;"'));
```

Comment: I got do it, but your method is more clean. Thanks. By a reason I will have to use your method and the other method in same time.

Comment: You may want to want to change `.*` to `\d*` or `.*?` so that the H="200" T="0" is preserved

Comment: @EdBallot I consciously chose NOT to fix the bugs in the original regexp. This code will do the same thing as the original PHP code (except that he also needs to add delimiters in the PHP).